# Is using blockhash a good source of randomness on PoS blockchains with a lot of blocks mined in a short period of time?

Tags: contract-design, mining, hash, blockchain-fork, games

I am trying to make a casino-like game using a smart contract and employing only on-chain data. I understand that on a blockchain like Ethereum a malicious miner can cheat the system by withholding the blocks he has mined. However what if use the same function on a blockchain where the blocks are found very quickly(such as fantom(FTM) or solana(SOL)), wouldn't it be impossible for a malicious miner to cheat the system since in the time frame between him placing his bet and the next block being found it would be almost impossible for him to find multiple blocks unless he has a huge ammount of coins at stake? Is it possible to make the system more secure by using hashes from multiple future blocks  i.e. 10 future blocks or is this impossible to code in Solidity?